# React native navigation (web, android and ios) Goes back to first screen

Tags: react-native, web, navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-web

Hey I'm using react native to build an app for android, ios and web, I'm using https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation for navigation, it works fine on android and IOs but on web I've stumbled open 2 problems.
First is the next screen always open in the same page, I want it to go to a new page.
Second, Let's assume I'm on the third screen in the stack and if I hit refresh in the browser It goes to the first screen(in my case the first screen is the login screen).
What can I do to solve this problem? is there any other navigation framework that I should use for web, android and ios, or do you have completely different thing to suggest?

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import LoginScreen from './screen/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screen/HomeScreen';
import AboutUsScreen from './screen/AboutUsScreen';
import ProgramsScreen from './screen/ProgramsScreen';
import ResourcesScreen from './screen/ResourcesScreen';
import NewsScreen from './screen/NewsScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="AboutUsScreen" component={AboutUsScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ProgramsScreen" component={ProgramsScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ResourcesScreen" component={ResourcesScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="NewsScreen" component={NewsScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Hey Hamza
Thanks for asking your question, could you please attach code samples to your question to help others understand what exactly you're looking at

Comment: hey, thanks you interest, I've added the question with the code that I'm using to switch the screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, I solved it, I created 2 App.js files, App.js for web and App.android.js for android, In App.android.js I used react navigation for navigating and for the web I used routes, Using routes removed the problem which was on refreshing the page the app would jump to the login screen.